# Extracting parts of paths in Java

Tags: java, file, path, filepath

I have a file path like this:

```
/home/Dara/Desktop/foo/bar/baz/qux/file.txt
```

In Java, I would like to be able to get the **top two** folders. Ie. `baz/qux` regardless of file path length or operating system (File path separators such as `/` `:` and `\`). I have tried to use the `subpath()` method in `Paths` but I can't seem to find a generic way to get the length of the file path.

Comment: What doesn't work using `Path.subpath()`?

Comment: Using `Path.subpath(0, 2)` gives me `home/Dara`. I would like to be able to say something like `Path.subpath(myPath.length() - 3, myPath.length() - 1` to get `baz/qux`.

Comment: Can't you use `Path.getNameCount()` for the length?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not yet pretty, however, you guess the direction:

```
File parent = file.getParentFile();
File parent2 = parent.getParentFile();
parent2.getName() + System.getProperty("path.separator") + parent.getName()
```

Another option:

```
final int len = path.getNameCount();
path.subpath(len - 3, len - 1)
```

Edit: You should either check len or catch the `IllegalArgumentException` to make your code more robust.

Answer (score 7):

The methods `getNameCount()` and `getName(int index)` of `java.nio.Path` should help you:

```
File f = new File("/home/Dara/Desktop/foo/bar/baz/qux/file.txt");
Path p = f.toPath();
int pathElements = p.getNameCount();
String topOne = p.getName(pathElements-2).toString();
String topTwo = p.getName(pathElements-3).toString();
```

Please be aware, that the result of `getNameCount()` should be checked for validity, before using it as an index for `getName()`.

Answer (score 4):

Using subpath and getNameCount.

```
    Path myPath = Paths.get("/home/Dara/Desktop/foo/bar/baz/qux/file.txt");
    Path subPath = myPath.subpath(myPath.getNameCount() -3, myPath.getNameCount() -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the String or use a [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: True, I am doing that now but I would be more comfortable using a more generic way.

Comment: what do you mean by more generic way?

Comment: Make sure to use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` and not specifically a `"/"` in your calls.

Answer (score 1):

`File.getParent()` will remove the filename.

And the path separator you will get with: `System.getProperty("file.separator")`.

Then you can use `String.split()` to get each part of the path.

Answer (score 1):

To get path parts in Koltin

```
fun subPaths(path: Path, levels: Int): List<Path> {
    return path.runningReduce { acc, value -> acc.resolve(value) }.take(levels)
}
```